# How do I get averages of groups of numbers in column? Keep getting "Error 1111:Invalid use of Group Functions"

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm relatively new to coding and trying to figure this out, but unfortunately I'm not having much luck.
Using MySQL, I have two tables (calls, and jobs) and I want to display columns from both tables. 
I need to get the average of groups of values from one column (scores - grouped by the number_id) and display the average score of each number_id, but only if the score is less than 5.

This is the code I have at the moment, but I keep getting Error 1111:Invalid use of Group Function:

```
SELECT job.id, job.number, job.number_id, COUNT(job.id) AS 'test_count', 
AVG(calls.score) AS 'score_avg'
FROM job LEFT JOIN calls ON job.id = calls.job_id
WHERE AVG(calls.score) > 5
GROUP BY job.number_id;
```

I can display the average value when I don't have the WHERE clause, but once I try to get the values less than 5, MySQL return the above error. Any advice would be much appreciated.

These average values are then due to be inserted in to a new table. I presume that once I figure out how to get the above query working, I can adjust it into an INSERT statement. Am I correct in thinking that?

Thanks!

Comment: `HAVING AVG(calls.score) > 5` instead of WHERE.

Comment: You are using the > sign instead of less than in your query also @Beany01

Answer (score 1):

`Where` clause is used to filter rows. Use `HAVING` clause to filter *groups*

```
SELECT job.id,
       job.number,
       job.number_id,
       Count(job.id)    AS 'test_count',
       Avg(calls.score) AS 'score_avg'
FROM   job
       LEFT JOIN calls
              ON job.id = calls.job_id
GROUP  BY job.number_id
HAVING Avg(calls.score) > 5
```

Or you need derived table and filter the scores where average is greater than `5`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT job.id,
               job.number,
               job.number_id,
               Count(job.id)    AS 'test_count',
               Avg(calls.score) AS 'score_avg'
        FROM   job
               LEFT JOIN calls
                      ON job.id = calls.job_id
        GROUP  BY job.number_id) a
WHERE  score_avg > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in the `WHERE` clause apply to one row at a time. You can't say anything about the group in the `WHERE` clause.

Expressions in the `HAVING` clause apply to one whole group at a time. You need the group to be defined before you can place a condition on which groups to include.

So your group-wise function `AVG()` can be used only in a `HAVING` clause.